# How do I find the information in a ArrayAdapter of a certain column from a database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

What I am trying to accomplish is to find out if there is information in a specific column from a database that is returned from the query.  if there is information in there then I am going to have a sound and a toast message.  The query part works fine and the information is shown in a listView just the way I want it.
How do I find out what is in that field?
Here is the code for the query and results:

```
public void doSearch(View v) {
String prefValue = UIHelper.getText(this, R.id.editText1);
    scans = datasource.findFiltered("isbn = " + prefValue, "isbn ASC");
    ArrayAdapter<Scan> adapter = new ScanListAdapter(this, scans);
    if (scans.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "ISBN Not Found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.miss);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } else {
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.chaching);
    mediaPlayer.start();


    Scan supply = scans.get(0);
    Log.i(LOGTAG,  supply+ " is at index ");

    if(null == supply) {

    } else { 
                Toast.makeText(this, "Requires Supply!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                MediaPlayer supplyPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.meep1);
                supplyPlayer.start();
            } 
    }
    }
```

Here is the query:

```
public List<Scan> findFiltered(String selection, String orderBy) {

Cursor cursor = database.query(ScanDBOpenHelper.TABLE_SCANS, allColumns, 
        selection, null, null, null, orderBy);

Log.i(LOGTAG, "Returned " +cursor.getCount() + " rows");

    List<Scan> scans = cursorToList(cursor);
return scans;
```

}

```
private List<Scan> cursorToList(Cursor cursor) {
List<Scan> scans = new ArrayList<Scan>();
if (cursor.getCount() >0) {
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Scan scan = new Scan();
        scan.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_ID)));
        scan.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_TITLE)));
        scan.setIsbn(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_ISBN)));
        scan.setAuthor(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_AUTHOR)));
        scan.setPrice(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_PRICE)));
        scan.setIePrice(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_IE)));
        scan.setMaxLimit(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_LIMIT)));
        scan.setSupply(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_SUPPLY)));
        scans.add(scan);    
    } 
} 
return scans;
```

The part that starts with Scan supply = scans.get(0) is where I am trying to find the information.  As it sits, it will do what I want, but I am not using the correct field.
    [image: Screen shot of emulator]
I need to get the information that is in the supply field.  Any suggestions?  If I am not being clear or you need more code, please let me know.

Comment: You don't provide any information on datasource. How are we supposed to know what's in there if we have nothing more than a variable name?

Comment: if your data model is an sqlite db then use a SimpleCursorAdapter, and not ArrayAdapter

Comment: How do I find out what is in that field? - Are you trying to see the details shown in list item?

Comment: If there is something in the field, ie needs cd, then I have a toast message and a sound that is played.  not all items need supply, so i need to alert the user to the ones that do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about?

```
for (Scan scan : scans) {
    String supply = scan.getSupply();
    if (supply != null && supply.length() > 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Requires Supply!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        MediaPlayer supplyPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.meep1);
        supplyPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: The only problem is that they may need something other than cd.  It can either require access code, access card, online resource, etc.  i would just like to know if that field is empty or not and then have it alert.

Comment: Changed my answer to check for empty supply

Comment: i had to remove the "".equals part since I only want to know if it is not empty.  otherwise this worked just like I needed, thanks.